# What are some error measures used for fitting PMFs?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, mean-square-error

I have a given PMF, $f_X(x)$, and am trying to create a fitted PMF, $g_X(x)$, that comes "as close as possible" to it, but am not sure what to use as a measure of fit. Simply minimizing standard error feels wrong, since it can produce fits that dramatically alter the relative probability of low values of $f_X$.

Currently I'm using 
$$\sum_{x\in X} \frac{\left[f_X(x)-g_X(x)\right]^2}{f_X(x)}$$
as my error measure, but that's just a guess that seems to give reasonable looking results.

Are there more suitable or standard error measures used for fitting PMFs?

Comment: Why isn't $f_X(x)$ itself the one that comes as close as possible?  Generally the answer to that would be that it is desired that $g_X(x)$ belong to a specified family of functions.  But you haven't told us about that. You might look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_chi-square_estimation ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Yes, sorry, that wasn't clear. $g_X(x)$ is constrained in ways that $f_X(x)$ is not.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been many years, but for what it's worth, the expression you wrote down is from information geometry! If we think of the space of probability distributions on $X$ as a manifold, we can make it a Riemannian manifold by equipping it with the information metric.

What you wrote down is the squared length of the *tangent vector at $f_X$ that points towards $g_X$*. This strikes me as a reasonable and natural measurement of the difference between the two distributions.

Answer (score 0):

In some situations, $\int\,f_X(x)\log\frac{f_X(x)}{g_X(x;\,a)}\, dx$ is used, or its equivalent in discrete cases. The goal is to choose parameters $a$ minimizing it. Have a look at the $G$ test.